# how to access the properties and children of a element with the this pointer jquery?

Tags: jquery

I am still working in my first jquery code. I have now a little problem that I don't know how to solve. I readed in severals tutorials that the following expretion is valid: `$('table tr')` with this is possible to have access to the `<tr>` in a table, or `$('select option')` is also giving me the access to the `<option>` tag of a select. 
Is it possible to express the same with the referens pointer `this`? Where `this` replace the Object?

How should be the correct expression?

Comment: So on what situation you want to access with `this`? Can you try to give an example..??

Comment: Hi!  with the answer of @Mihai Morariu I solve the problem. Was very simple really :)

Comment: Yea.. But compared to `jquery` methods using selectors is good with performance..

Comment: I have another question, I don't know if I can post just here, maybe you can answer me :) How I can ask to a element when a event was fire? Example I want to know when the onclick event of a select box was fire, I don't want to do nothing with the event, just to know when was fire

Comment: What you need is the "click" event. See here: https://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: in fact for `select` you need to look into `change` event..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try $(this).children('option') or $(this).find('option'). The second one is a bit slower, though.